# Como melhorar desempenho do ajax update ? JSF

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, hibernate

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para restaurante e tenho um dataGrid que atualiza o outra.
Por exemplo: clico na classe e atualiza o dataGrid de produtos.

Funciona, porém o resultado é meio lento.

Estou usando um `<h:commandLink>` com update:

```
<p:commandLink  actionListener="#{mesaControle.setClasseFiltro(grupo)}"
                action="#{mesaControle.validaBuscarProduto()}" 
                update="form:produtos">
    <button style="background-color: #0b66b1; height: 55px; width: 100px;">
    <br/>
    <strong style="color: #f6f6f6">#{grupo.nome}</strong></button>
</p:commandLink>
```

E filtro da seguinte maneira:

```
public List<Produto> listaClasse(Classe produtoFiltro) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("FROM Produto As a WHERE a.classe = :para order by id asc");
    q.setParameter("para", produtoFiltro);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

---

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas a performance deixa a desejar.
Como posso melhorar a performance?

Comment: O que demora? A consulta no banco de dados ou a atualização do componente na view?

Comment: Cara provavelmente é a atualização do componente na view, preciso de algo dinâmico, algo que quando eu clicar no botão, ele ja renderize do lado.. No momento demora de 2 a 3 segundos apos o clique .

Comment: Coloca um `System.out.println()` no inicio e no final do metodo de consulta do banco e compare se um demora mais do que o outro... Acho que é isso que está atrasando hehe

Comment: beleza vou tentar e posto e resultado

Comment: cara, sendo a pesquisa que esta atrasando rs vc sabe alguma outra maneira dele fazer essa pesquisa] Notei que na classe que tem mais produtos ele demora um pouco mais.

Comment: Sabia! hehe. Cara, nesse caso existem algumas coisas que você pode fazer: criar index para sua tabela (se ainda não existir), limitar a quantidade de registros buscados por página do dataGrid, e acho que você não precisa fazer `FROM Produto As a`. Acho que só `FROM Produto a` já funciona (não que seja esse o problema)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70236/discussion-between-leandro-santos-and-igor-venturelli).